# Is wolframcloud accessible from mobile devices?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, free-wolfram-engine

I am having trouble accessing the free online platform for the most part of the last couple of weeks.

I used to log on without any problem from my mobile device but for some reason I have not been able to use it since. After logging on, the platform seems to be loading in the browser but the processes never completes.

I wanted to ask if others are experiencing the same problem or if it's just me. In case I am the only one experiencing this issue, please let me know if there's a workaround.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

At 27 february 2020 I uploaded a formpage to the cloud. I send the URL by WhatsApp to several other people. Everybody could reach and see my app.

Comment: did you upload it manually or using code? can you access your lab.wolframcloud.com account from your browser on your mobile device?

Comment: I used CloudDeploy. Then WL upload it to the cloud for me. But i do not have a lab.wolframcould. I send it my develop.wolframcloud en to my worfram.com cloud. Maybe there is some difference with your lab environment.